# How to write typescript modules that support amd and plain browsers

Tags: typescript, amd

I want to write reusable components using TypeScript. So I want people using AMD modules or people who are not be able to use my component.

Can I use TypeScript to write modules that support both AMD require and plain browser support as a fallback? I know there is UMD support in typescript which supports both AMD and CommonJS, but I haven't found a way in their documentation a way to add a fallback to plain browser support.

Comment: @basarat, I disagree with this. I think what the OP and myself are trying to do is to make a JS class that can be accessed like `d3.select()`. For this common pattern to work TS needs to allow for a global browser name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use TypeScript to write modules that support both AMD require and plain browser support as a fallback? I know there is UMD support in typescript which supports both AMD and CommonJS, but I haven't found a way in their documentation a way to add a fallback to plain browser support.

This isn't supported. Globals are a bad idea. Recommend moving to npm (commonjs) all things